# What (if any) are the distinctions between an Azure WebJob running locally (on my machine) versus hosted in Azure

Tags: async-await, httpwebrequest, azure-webjobs

I have written a ConsoleApplication (not using any pre-defined Azure templates) that runs as a web job in Azure. The job is designed to be continuous and the Main entry to the application looks as follows:

```
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
        config.UseServiceBus();
        var host = new JobHost(config);
        host.RunAndBlock();
```

The essence of this web job is that it picks messages up from a 'notifications' service bus queue and sends notifications. For the purpose of this particular problem when dequeued, the notification message is then turned into an HttpWebRequest which calls into 'Slack' (with an await on the GetResponseStream)

All of my methods and de-queue methods are async Tasks:

```
public static async Task ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("notifications")] BrokeredMessage receivedMessage,TextWriter logger)
```

And I have await's on my notifier that sends the relevant messages.

You can assume that I have a service elsewhere that is pumping messages onto this queue and that that service is working fine.

When I run this console app *locally* everything runs absolutely perfectly, all messages are turned into web requests and slack receives everyone of my messages flawlessly, *everytime*. When I host this web job in Azure the HttpWebRequests time-out to which I have a 'feeling' relates to the number of concurrent requests allowed or perhaps a potential thread lock somewhere (this is pure guess work).

All I get in terms of an exception is a WebException which is a timeout. I've introduced retry methods and I've introduced lots of logging but I'm struggling to see anything that will help me. Retries seem to make no difference, they retry and then fail making me think it a synchronisation context thing.

In web projects there are config keys like:

```
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
```

Do I need this in my console app? Does this even make sense in a console app? Any thoughts on how I can better solve this, anything obvious I'm doing wrong? Are there any distinct differences (like the way it is run) that makes the app behave differently when hosted?

Comment: I think perhaps that my reference to Azure and WebJobs in general here is a Red Herring. In the end I determined that the missing configuration section <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web> resolved the thread lock issues with async await calls on the http stack.